# Why does a 3d model render differently in a SubScene than in Scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

Rendered with flag set to true, camera set to the subscene, and 
then rotated:

[image: Rendered]

Xylophone rendered in SubScene:

[image: Xylophone rendered in SubScene]

Xylophone rendered in Scene:

[image: Xylophone rendered in Scene]

Using Oracle's Xylophone 3D example, I have encountered a curious problem. ([Xylophone.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/xylophonejava.htm))
When it is rendered in Scene it looks correct.  When it is rendered in SubScene it does not.  Has anybody encountered this?  Is there a solution or workaround?

Here is the modified code that creates a SubScene:

```
final SubScene sub = new SubScene(camOffset, 800,600, false, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    pane.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
    pane.getChildren().add(sub);
    final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the depthBuffer-flag (4th parameter) to true in your SubScene-Constructor: 
final SubScene sub = new SubScene(camOffset, 800,600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
In a 3d scenario the depthBuffer is needed for depth sorted rendering (see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html).
Moreover (if not already done) the camera should be assigned to the subScene and not to the scene:
sub.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
Then everything should work as expected.

Edit:
In addition, the applying of a gradient to a subscene fill does not seem to work, see 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088605
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGx4CV_K5U8&feature=youtu.be
A possible workaround is the applying of the gradient to the pane containing the subscene.

On the whole, in the start-method of the Xylophone-class replace

```
final Scene scene = new Scene(camOffset, 800, 600, true);
scene.setFill(new RadialGradient(225, 0.85, 300, 300, 500, false,
                                  CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]
                                  { new Stop(0f, Color.BLUE),
                                    new Stop(1f, Color.LIGHTBLUE) }));
scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
```

with

```
final SubScene sub = new SubScene(camOffset, 800,600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED); // set depthBuffer = true
sub.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
pane.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
pane.getChildren().add(sub);
final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600, true);
// Shift the RadialGradient from the Scene to the AnchorPane (and NOT to the SubScene).
RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(225, 0.85, 300, 300, 500, false,
                                                   CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]
                                                   { new Stop(0f, Color.BLUE),
                                                     new Stop(1f, Color.LIGHTBLUE) });
pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(radialGradient, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
```

This code works on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work..  I have added a 3rd image of the xylophone with the depth buffer flag set to true, and then rotated to match the position of the other 2 pictures.  Camera is assigned to the subscene.

Comment: Thanks. The only modification I made to the source code was what I posted.  This problem is appearing in other projects and on other machines.  Not restricted to my machine.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too. I'll just add two things: There is a typo in the back face, and it should be `backFace.setTranslateZ(0.5*size);`. And since the `Cube` class doesn't use a proper 3D cube, but a bunch of 2D rectangles, those could be easily replaced with: `Box box = new Box(size, size, size); box.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(color)); getChildren().add(box);`.